# Incompatible Target Framework on Visual Studio Community

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I`ve been trying to make a unit test in my project following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/walkthrough-creating-and-running-unit-tests-for-managed-code?view=vs-2019

But when I try to reference my project on step 5 shows this:

"Project(Incompatible target framework: .NETFramework, version=v4.7)"

Anyone has found a solution?

First of all, Thanks.

Comment: The tutorial says that both project should be targetting .NET Core, but it seems your Test project is targetting .NET framework. Can you check what is the target framework ?

Answer (score 0):

I just faced a similar issue. I was developing from a macbook and I notice when you start a new project, somehow by default it starts with .Net Framework and when you add a unit test (MSTest in my case) it sets it from .Net Core and the two are just not compatible targets as it says.

How I solved this is, at the start of the new project, I select under Web and Console -> App ->Console Application (since you are doing a console app from the shared link). Then when I hit next, I am given the option to select a target framework. There I select .Net Core and go on with other processes. Then when I added my unit test from there it worked with no issues.

Try that lets see if it works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can check TargetFramework property in both projects. They can be different. For example:

Main project:

```
<TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

Test project:

```
<TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
```

If they're the same, then everything should work.